# Phonegap button state CSS change

Tags: cordova, mobile, touch

I am new to phonegap and despite some googling I haven't really figured out what's the best solution for creating buttons.

I mean, I want a clear indication that the button is pressed when i press it. If my press lasts longer, the button should look like it's "down". I tried using CSS hover and active states but it's not a satisfying result.

Would you recommend using some touch event library or what?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a pleasing solution now. It includes using xui.js touchstart and touchend events. This is what i was looking for.

[No reaction from my HTML buttons in phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5894212/no-reaction-from-my-html-buttons-in-phonegap)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any mobile frameworks like jQuery Mobile/Kendo UI Mobile? They have lots of mobile widgets including buttons. It's gonna be a big pain to create all the touch widgets from scratch.

Comment: I prefer creating my own styles, and I wouldn't like to overwrite all this stuff again with my custom styles

Comment: See this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063308/touch-css-pseudo-class-or-something-similar . you will have to create your own touch event and then do the animation.